# I changed a few things around and my php redirects me saying it cannot handle the request.

Tags: php, forms, web

I changed a few things on my page and now my php form isn't working saying it cannot handle the request. It takes me to an error screen but does not redirect me or create the cab file. Can someone look at it and let me know where it's broken? I know I've used a lot of inline css formatting but this is a quick a dirty thing I need to put together for a project I am working on. I need you Obi Wan, you're my only hope! :)

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" name="register" style="margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-9 mb-2 mb-md-0">

              <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter your name..." style="width:20em; margin-bottom:1em;" required>
              <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter your email..." style="width:20em; margin-bottom:1em;" required>
              <input name="phone" id="phone" type="tel" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter your phone number..." style="width:20em; margin-bottom:1em;">
              <input name="gsname" id="gsname" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter your guest or spouse's name..." style="width:20em;">

              <p style=" text-align:left; font-size:26px; margin-top:1em;">Choose the date that works for you...</p>
              <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date" value="Tuesday, April 24" style="height:25px; width:25px; margin-top:.5em; float:left;" />
              <p for="tuesday" style="font-size:22px; text-align:left; margin-left:2em; font-weight:bold;">Tuesday, April 24th 11 AM - 12:30 PM </p>
              <br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date" value="Thursday, April 26th" style="height:25px; width:25px; margin-top:.5em; margin-bottom:.5em; float:left; " />
              <p for="thursday" style="font-size:22px; text-align:left; margin-left:2em; font-weight:bold;">Thursday, April 26th 11 AM - 12:30 PM </p>
              <br>
              <p style=" text-align:left; font-size:26px;">Would you like our newsletter?</p>
              <input type="checkbox" name="opt_in" id="opt_in" value="newsletter opt-in" style="height:25px; width:25px; margin-top:.5em; float:left; " />
              <p for="tuesday" style="font-size:22px; text-align:left; margin-left:2em;">Yes, Send me your newsletter</p>

            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" style="width:15em;">Register Now</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

and my php script

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$name = $_POST['name']
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$gsname = $_POST['gsname'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$opt_in = $_POST['opt_in'];
$open = fopen("formdata.csv", "a");
fputcsv($open, array($name, $email, $phone, $gsname, $date, $opt_in));
fclose($open);

//  To redirect form on a particular page
header("Location:https://www.google.com");
}
else {
header("Location:https://www.charter.com");
}

?>
```

Comment: *"isn't working"* doesn't help much

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It was a vague title. I changed it around.

Comment: Check your error logs to see if there's any information there.

Comment: Still, no logs? No error messages? Just "can't handle the request"? I mean, this php code must be running somewhere. And that somewhere should produce logs with error messages. Can you please check and show them?

Comment: I don't see any logs on the server. It says it's an http 500 error if that helps.

Comment: Look, we're as blind as you are on this. Try rolling back your changes, re-introduce them one at a time and see when it blows up.

Comment: Trying that now

Comment: I must have messed up somestuff on the last php script. I found that I set the variables first and then if they did or didn't work then they would go down the line and run into the right statement. Sorry guys.. I'm going to close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the if statement for my script because I didn't want to check if I clicked the submit button, now I have it checking if I have an email. I could use regex to determine if it is an actual email but I'll leave that alone now.

```
<?php

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$gsname = $_POST['gsname'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$opt_in = $_POST['opt_in'];
if (isset($email)){
$open = fopen("formdata.csv", "a");
fputcsv($open, array($name, $email, $phone, $gsname, $date, $opt_in));
fclose($open);

//  To redirect form on a particular page
header("Location:thanks.html");
}
else (
header("Location:oops.html")
)
?>
```